# Converting "[myObject][1][application]" string to useable path on JObject

Tags: c#, json

First let me start off by showing you what I am trying to accomplish by using pseudo code. (Yes I know this example is not possible)

```
var path = "[DocInfo][Type]";
var doc = couchDbCall();
var specificProperty = doc[path];
```

I want to turn a string into a literaly path accessor in code but cannot seem to find any examples etc; probably due to my lack of a good search query.

```
{
  "_id": "bb9f9e13-218a-4403-9920-79b0d353634b",
  "_rev": "2-908d1257d7324a8b6f1c333cbefe2e41",
  "Name": "conversionTest2",
  "DocInfo": {
  "Type": "Application",
  "Platform": "test",
  "Version": "12",
  "VersionRelId": -1,
  "Category": "Communications and Messaging",
  "Created": {
  "CreatedDate": "3/19/2015 7:56:07 PM",
  "User": {
    "Id": "bf51f6ce-d3f7-46ff-9ff0-c1e60c2ded44",
    "Name": "Adrian Campos",
    "Email": "adrian.campos@bizdox.com"
  }
},
"Template": "Other Application",
"TemplateVersion": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your json or something?

Comment: 1. Split it to an array of names 2. Recursively retrieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.3) (get it via NuGet):

```
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonString);
string type = o.DocInfo.Type; // gets "Application"
var doc = couchDbCall(); 
var specificProperty = doc[type]; // assuming doc takes a string as key
```

UPDATE:

that works also:

```
string type = o["DocInfo"]["Type"];
```

UPDATE 2:

as far as I understand this little recursive method will help you out (note that there's no error handling whatsoever):

```
private string DoMyPaths(List<string> paths, JToken token)
{

    string s = paths[0];
    if (paths.Count > 1)
    {
        paths.RemoveAt(0);
        JToken result = token[s];
        return DoMyPaths(paths, result);
    }
    return token[s].ToString();
}
```

now you can pass in your path (delimited by '.'):

```
string myPath = "DocInfo.Created.User.Name";
var paths = myPath.Split('.').ToList();
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var  result = DoMyPaths(paths, o);
```

result:

```
"Adrian Campos"
```

Comment: but the line `string type = o.DocInfo.Type` requires me to hardcode the path. I'm trying to generalize a task so we can use it regardless what property by just passing in a string with the path to the property. I guess a better way of explaining it is trying to do the C# equivalent of `eval(myValue)`

Comment: It's still hardcoded in the event that I need to go 3 levels deep into the node. Or even 4. I'm guessing I will just have to write a traverse method to recursively find the property :(. I was hoping C# had some awesome extension method or something.

Comment: that's not too hard mate. just split your 'inputstring' and then go down the levels and pass it as param.

Comment: @Adrian updated again. hope this will help you along.

Comment: Thanks alot man for going out of your way. I'll just pretend I still have to implement this at work tomorrow lol 